# Is there a keyboard shortcut to start a comment on a Trello card?

Tags: trello, keyboard-shortcuts

There's a shortcut for nearly everything else, and since some of the shortcuts have changed (<kbd>a</kbd> is now <kbd>m</kbd>, even though both work, for example) I wonder if there is a shortcut to start a comment on a currently open card.

Comment: Inspect the page source on a Trello card page and search for "accesskey=". Do you see any HTML elements relating to starting a comment that include an accesskey attribute? If not, it is pretty easy to add keyboard shortcuts to a web app using client-side javascript.

Comment: They so need this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately not, though the [shortcuts help page](https://trello.com/shortcuts) will be kept up-to-date as new shortcuts are added.

Answer (score 4):

Although there is no shortcut for this available - on Chrome 55/Windows 10, with a card already open, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) to go to location bar and then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Cursor will land on Comment text box.

Answer (score -1):

This post is currently the top search result on Google so here is an alternative (albeit still indirect) method:

With the card open, press `E` (shortcut to edit the description), then `TAB` four times. This should put you directly into the new comment text box.

Comment: Sometimes you need to press `TAB` more than four times, when there are images or documents.